# What JavaScript API schema is for guaranteeing Data Consistency in platforms like React-native?

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, v8, ecmascript-5

I am trying to develop a JavaScript API, and a set of patterns, to use going forward that makes sense and is intuitive for people to use. **What is the best way to batch data consistency checks together with writes, or other reads, when calling CRUD JavaScript functions that run through the react-native bridge?**

Here is an example **scenario**: There are business critical UI components with several fields:

1. Portfolio Value
2. Discount Percentage
3. Calculated Discount
4. Net Fees.

The Discount can change based on market fluctuation (svc call), sales team updates (interactive user updates),  based off quantity (biz logic), or based on some machine learning models (svc call) that the organization is more likely to order again. Mutations can come from the native side events, remote services (w/ webhooks sometimes), and even the apps business logic. How does a developer guaranteed that the data they read at some point in time is the same data they read when they write new data back?

Some possible pseudocode again, that just doesn't seem right:

```
var currentDiscount = await someModel.getDiscountValue();
var currentPortfolioValue = await someModel.getPortFolioValue();
var netFees = currentServiceRate - (currentServiceRate * currentDiscount);
/**
* In order to guarantee that the currentDiscount didnt change since it was retrieved
* this API batch-sends the value the original recieved value along with the update action.
* This means the platform, on the native/view side, will have to synchronously conditional check the current value
* with the value in the UI, if it is the same, update the net fees field. 
*/
try {
await someModel.UpdateFeeValue(netFees, [ currentDiscount ]);
} catch (err) {
console.log(err);
}
```

Data consistency is a hard thing to guarantee when data/models are being mutated from all different directions. Handling changes from multiple different routes including the interactive users of the application, events from services, and even application logic. In React-native due to its decoupled nature ( batch bridge) there is less of a guarantee of data read/write consistency between the JavaScript application logic and the native view layers.

Comment: You should look into redux and similar state containers

Comment: Thanks @nadavvadan. Redux is something I have used in the past, but even though Redux does a great job of getting closer to data consistency it doesn't solve it. The possibility of data being out of sync is minimized by events firing from the native side, updating the state tree in redux, and changes from the JavaScript side. The problem is, when there is a action back over the IPC bridge, it could be before the state had a chance to update on the JavaScript side. This means when it hits the native side it is out of sync and no longer consistent. I think we need to batch pattern here.